# cycle through plots generated with function using slider

Tags: r, shiny

I have five R scripts sourced in my shiny app that I am running in renderPlot. A series of unique mutations are contained in each script along with ggplot code to generate a boxplot with specific quantile values. Each is a unique function that accepts my input$variable.
I would like to source the scripts in Shiny and cycle through the plots based on the user slider selection of quantile values.
I haven't had any trouble generating each plot individually, the problem is running them all together.
Each variable of "Name" has a unique value in each of these functions. So ideally, I would like to select a variable and view each of its plots with the slider.
Is there an easy way to do this? I have tried to link the slider input with each specific plot but haven't had any luck.

```
source("s_75.R")
source("s_80.R")
source("s_85.R")
source("s_90.R")
source("s_95.R")
# Define UI for pair interaction app ----
ui <- pageWithSidebar(

  # App title ----
  headerPanel("Set"),

  # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
  sidebarPanel(# Input: Selector for variable to plot against  ----
      selectInput("variable", "Name:", qc$S),
                sliderInput("quantile", "Quantile Range:",
                  min = 75, max = 95, value = c(85), step = 5)),
      
      
 

  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
  mainPanel(
    h1("Header 1"),
    plotOutput("plot", width = "100%")
  ))







# Define server logic to plot various variables against 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
output$plot <- renderPlot(s_75(input$variable),
height = 600, width = 800)
output$plot2 <- renderPlot(s_80(input$variable),
height = 600, width = 800)

output$plot3 <- renderPlot(s_85(input$variable),
height = 600, width = 800)

output$plot4 <- renderPlot(s_90(input$variable),
height = 600, width = 800)

output$plot5 <- renderPlot(s_95(input$variable),
height = 600, width = 800)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could do this. I think the most concise way
I could think of is to use the `get()` command. This will let you find an object in your environment when called as a string (`input$variable`). The only new items are the reprex at the top and the server body. If I misunderstood the prompt, let me know and I'll try to update my answer.

```r
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# reprex ----
qc <- 
  mtcars |> 
  pivot_longer(everything()) |> 
  print()

s_75 <- function(var) ggplot(mtcars, aes(get(var))) + geom_bar() 
s_80 <- function(var) ggplot(mtcars, aes(get(var))) + geom_dotplot() 
s_85 <- function(var) ggplot(mtcars, aes(get(var))) + geom_histogram() 
s_90 <- function(var) ggplot(mtcars, aes(get(var), 1)) + geom_count() 
s_95 <- function(var) ggplot(mtcars, aes(get(var))) + geom_density() 


# ui ----
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  # App title ----
  headerPanel("Set"),

  # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
  sidebarPanel( # Input: Selector for variable to plot against  ----
    selectInput("variable", "Name:", unique(qc$name)),
    sliderInput("quantile", "Quantile Range:",
      min = 75, max = 95, value = c(85), step = 5
    )
  ),
  # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
  mainPanel(
    h1("Header 1"),
    plotOutput("plot", width = "100%")
  )
)


# server ----
# Define server logic to plot various variables against 
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  fn <- reactive(get(paste0("s_", input$quantile)))
  output$plot <-  renderPlot(fn()(input$variable), height = 600, width = 800)
                          #    ^^^ note that the reactive value goes fn()(var)
}
  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you so much!